# Blurred bitmap on canvas

Tags: java, android-studio

I have View-based element in main activity and [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTAQS.png) in drawable folder

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private Bitmap mSprite;

    public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plank);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mSprite, 0.f, 0.f, null);
    }
}
```

The image is displayed but looks blurry and too large ([ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCbDX.jpg)). How can I get the actual size of bitmap and draw in on canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone faced the above issue: just put your image in `nodpi` folder and it will match its actual size.